# angularJS validation firing onblur for IE10

Tags: angularjs, validation

I have a validation form working well on chrome/FF/IE8/9 but on IE10 after loading the page its firing the validation events when I am clicking the input element and then outside of element.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Username:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input id="username" name="username" ng-model="username" type="input"
               ng-class="{'error-org' : userForm.username.$invalid && !userForm.username.$pristine}"
               class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required>
        <label ng-show="userForm.username.$invalid && !userForm.username.$pristine" class="error-org">Please enter a username</label>
    </div>
</div>
```